# Getting text emotions using php library?

Tags: php, oop

Could you advise some php5 library wich i can teach to guess emotions in texts? (happy comment, angry comment, etc)

For example i need to check in my code if comment "I love your product!" is positive or negative and set appropriate status for this comment in my DB.

I found one but it's too old and hardcoded so i hope on your help.

Comment: You'll also need to include a sarcasm detector… *"Don't you just __love__ questions like this?"* ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I know of [EmoTE](http://jessefulton.com/playground/emote-api), it's a (partial) PHP port of [Synesketch](http://www.synesketch.krcadinac.com/wiki/index.php?title=Main_Page) which seems to be quite good.

Beware that for languages other than English you need to get your own emotive text corpus.

There are also some [uClassify](http://www.uclassify.com/) classifiers, such as [Mood](http://www.uclassify.com/browse/prfekt/Mood) and [Sentiment](http://www.uclassify.com/browse/uClassify/Sentiment) (which seems to be the one you're looking for) but they work by training bayesian networks and they don't seem to provide the kind of detailed data that EmoTE provides. Here are some tests using the comments on this question:

---

**Input (uClassify - Sentiment Classifier):**

> I love your product!

**Output:**

> 1. positive (99.6 %)
> 2. negative (0.4 %)

---

**Input (uClassify - Sentiment Classifier):**

> Explain a bit more please

**Output:**

> 1. positive (67.1 %)
> 2. negative (32.9 %)

---

**Input (uClassify - Sentiment Classifier):**

> I think not possible

**Output:**

> 1. negative (92.4 %)
> 2. positive (7.6 %)

---

**Input (uClassify - Sentiment Classifier):**

> Don't you just love questions like this?

**Output:**

> 1. negative (86.0 %)
> 2. positive (14.0 %)

---

Seems to do the job. Also, uClassify has an [API](http://www.uclassify.com/ApiDocumentation.aspx) and [self-hosted solutions](http://www.uclassify.com/Products.aspx) that you can use to classify and train existing classifiers with your own data, which might be useful depending on your exact needs.

Comment: Uh, very nice sarcasm detector! +1